# How to place select2 process results to tr class

Tags: jquery, ajax

When I rendered the HTML data, the following code was loading the HTML data with the success function:

```
$(document).on("change", ".product", function() {
        var selectval = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: '/purchase-order/ajax/load-attrs/',
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                'product': $(this).parents('tr').find(".product").val()
            },
            success: function (data) {
                selectval.parents('tr').find(".product_attr").html(data);
                console.log(data)
            }
        });
    });
```

All I need is:
How do I populate data in a specific class in the Select 2 process result? How do I use this `selectval.parents('tr').find(".product_attr")` inside `processResults`?

```
$(document).on("change", ".product", function() {
            var selectval = $(this);
            $.ajax({
                url: '/purchase-order/ajax/load-attrs/',
                type: "POST",
                dataType: 'json',
                data: {
                    'product': $(this).parents('tr').find(".product").val()
                },
                processResults: function (data) {
    
                    return {
                        results: $.map(data, function (item) {
                            return {id: item.id, text: item.sku};
                        })
                    };
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    selectval.parents('tr').find(".product_attr").html(data);
                    console.log(data)
                }
            });
        });
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated